# Convert 2 columns dataframe to a 2 dimensional matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe

Hi I am trying to convert an R dataframe with 2 character columns to a matrix. Here is an example of what I am trying to do:

suppose I have this dataframe:

```
name  work 
one   test1
one   test2
two   test1
two   test3
three test3
```

And I would like to turn it into this matrix

```
name  test1  test2  test3 
one     1      1      0   
two     1      0      1   
three   0      0      1
```

Any idea how I can accomplish this in R  please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DF <- read.table(text="name  work 
one   test1
one   test2
two   test1
two   test3
three test3", header=TRUE)

table(DF)

       work
name    test1 test2 test3
  one       1     1     0
  three     0     0     1
  two       1     0     1
```

Comment: @user1375640, try `View(as.data.frame.matrix(t))`.

Comment: This works great, but when I assign the table(DF) like: t = table(DF), then I try to View(t) I get 3 columns                                             
name  work  Freq
    one   test1  1

Is there a chance to have the dataframe to look like the output you show above with each work as a column?

Answer (score 2):

I have two R words for you: `data.matrix` and `xtabs`.

```
 data.matrix(DF)

 xtabs( ~ name+work, data=DF)
```

You do not need to do the conversion to a matrix to get `xtabs` to work and, as always in R, these values will print out at the console but 'DF' remains unchanged unless you assign (`<-`) the values to 'DF'.

You may notice that the column of names is "out of order" (one, three, two). (Why didn't the authors of the English language make the text version of numbers lexically sort properly?) You can manipulate the levels of a factor:

```
> DF$name <- factor(DF$name, levels=levels(DF$name)[c(1,3,2)] )
> xtabs( ~ name+work, data=DF)
       work
name    test1 test2 test3
  one       1     1     0
  two       1     0     1
  three     0     0     1
```